# Graphing an equation subject to constraints

Tags: python, matplotlib

[Here is an image of the formula I am supposed to use, and some sample graphs that it should look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2wF1.png)

[Here is an image that states the question I am working on.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj8o2.png)

What I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot asplt
import math

def graph (formula):
x = np.arrange(-4,4,0.1)
y = formula(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()

def my_formula(x):
return ((n**(n-.5))/(math.factorial(n-1)))*((1+x/(math.sqrt(n)))**(n-1))*
  (math.e**(-n*(1+x/(math.sqrt(n)))))
n=1

graph(my_formula)
```

What I can't figure out is how to include the x>-sqrt(n) constraint into the equation. Any help at all would be much appreciated!!

-This is for a class that's not even about programming, yet we have to do this sort of stuff anyway, so I'm really not that great at it

Answer (score 0):

The `x > sqrt(n)` constraint is putting a limit on the range of x-values, and you can easily do this when you create the x array.

Below is one way to do this (see the line with `max` and the subsequent line), but I also set the `xlim` of the graph to the -4 to 4 range to make it easy to compare different n-values:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import factorial, sqrt

def graph(formula, n):
    xmin = max(-sqrt(n), -4) # set the lower x limit for the calculation
    x = np.arange(xmin,4,0.1)
    y = formula(x, n)
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.xlim(-4, 4)  # set the graph limits to the full range
    plt.show()

def my_formula(x, n):
    z = 1 + x/sqrt(n)
    a = n**(n-.5)/factorial(n-1)
    b = z**(n-1)
    c = np.exp(-n*z)
    return  a*b*c

n = 4
graph(my_formula, n)
```

The graph below has `n=4` so `xmin=-2`.
[image]

Also, here I rewrote your code a bit too, though these were mostly for clarity.  First, I passed in `n` as a variable, since the multiple graphs are changing `n` (and if you want to treat `n` as a constant, put it directly after the imports so people can find it).  Second, I imported the math functions into the global namespace as math equations written in code are complicated enough without all the weight from the namespaces.  Third, I broke the three terms of the equation into bite sized pieces.  Overall, readability is important.